# is there a standard name for opposite of assert?

Tags: language-agnostic, assert

What I should name of a function that quits execution a condition equals true ? Deny ? Is there a common established name ?

```
anti_assert(1=1, errmsg);
```

For me it is easier to go that way because then it is possible to do macro in c/c++ like:

```
#define anti_assert(expression) anti_assert(expresstion, #expression)
```

And then in log I have the fragment of code that triggered the issue.

Comment: Why not just use `assert` and put a `!` in front of your condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really like `refute` from Ruby's [Minitest](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-refute). Makes it instantly clear what we want (assert) vs what we don't want (refute).

Comment: Good for brief JMeter assertion labels :)

Answer (score 1):

check antonyms at http://thesaurus.com/browse/assert
but i don't like any of that. if i had to choose one i would use 'prevent'. but i think it's not established because it's not needed. assertion in this form has less and less usage because it's not very readable. usually other forms are being used. example from java:

```java
assertThat(actualValue).isEqualTo(expectedValue)
assertThat(actualValue).isNotEqualTo(expectedValue)
assertThat(actualValue).containsSubstring(substring)
assertThat(actualValue).has(feature)
assertThat(actualValue).is(expectedValue)
```

other languages have libraries allowing you to use similar syntax. in such form, you don't really need anything opposite to assert